# Category of LCAG's "measures" the difference between the integers and the reals: what does this mean?

Tags: real-numbers, intuition, abelian-groups, integers, locally-compact-groups

The Wikipedia article on Locally compact abelian Groups (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_abelian_group) has the following excerpt in the Categorical properties section:

> Clausen (2017) shows that the category LCA of locally compact abelian groups measures, very roughly speaking, the difference between the integers and the reals. More precisely, the algebraic K-theory spectrum of the category of locally compact abelian groups and the ones of Z and R lie in a homotopy fiber sequence
> $${\displaystyle K(\mathbf {Z} )\to K(\mathbf {R} )\to K(LCA).}$$

This catches my attention because it looks like something really cool is being said, but unfortunately I am completely clueless as to what any of it means. For context I am now entering my 1st year of grad school, so pretty much every sentence after "reals." is like Chinese to me.

I would be thankful if someone could explain to me what this statement is saying in a digestible way.

Comment: I finished my undergrad recently and am about to enter first year of grad school. So my mathematical knowledge isn't that of an average man on the street but it's not particularly advanced either